# Jodatime timezone conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, timezone-offset

I'm using the Joda time to validate timestamp with time zone. When I passed invalid date or time it worked as expected. For example, when I pass 99 as seconds it gave the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot  
parse "20131231235999+00": Value 99 for secondOfMinute must be in the range [0,59]
```

I was expecting it to throw a similar exception with I passed invalid time zone as well.
I was expecting this for UTC offsets values less than -12 and greater than +14 hours (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset). It did give the following error when the offset value exceed 23 hours.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
format: "20131231235959+24" is malformed at "24"
```

I think I'm missing something since it indicates an error for 24th hour. Can someone explain why it allows offset values < -12 and > 14 hours.

Given below is a sample program with output for different offsets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException
{
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ").withZoneUTC();
    String dateString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            dateString = "20131231235959+0" + i;
            DateTime dt1 = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
            System.err.println(dateString + " = " + dt1);
        }
        else
        {
            dateString = "20131231235959+" + i;
            DateTime dt1 = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
            System.err.println(dateString + " = " + dt1);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
        {
            dateString = "20131231235959-0" + i;
            DateTime dt1 = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
            System.err.println(dateString + " = " + dt1);
        }
        else
        {
            dateString = "20131231235959-" + i;
            DateTime dt1 = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
            System.err.println(dateString + " = " + dt1);
        }
    }
}

Output:

20131231235959+00 = 2013-12-31T23:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-00 = 2013-12-31T23:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+01 = 2013-12-31T22:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-01 = 2014-01-01T00:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+02 = 2013-12-31T21:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-02 = 2014-01-01T01:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+03 = 2013-12-31T20:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-03 = 2014-01-01T02:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+04 = 2013-12-31T19:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-04 = 2014-01-01T03:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+05 = 2013-12-31T18:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-05 = 2014-01-01T04:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+06 = 2013-12-31T17:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-06 = 2014-01-01T05:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+07 = 2013-12-31T16:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-07 = 2014-01-01T06:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+08 = 2013-12-31T15:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-08 = 2014-01-01T07:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+09 = 2013-12-31T14:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-09 = 2014-01-01T08:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+10 = 2013-12-31T13:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-10 = 2014-01-01T09:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+11 = 2013-12-31T12:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-11 = 2014-01-01T10:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+12 = 2013-12-31T11:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-12 = 2014-01-01T11:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+13 = 2013-12-31T10:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-13 = 2014-01-01T12:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+14 = 2013-12-31T09:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-14 = 2014-01-01T13:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+15 = 2013-12-31T08:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-15 = 2014-01-01T14:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+16 = 2013-12-31T07:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-16 = 2014-01-01T15:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+17 = 2013-12-31T06:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-17 = 2014-01-01T16:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+18 = 2013-12-31T05:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-18 = 2014-01-01T17:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+19 = 2013-12-31T04:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-19 = 2014-01-01T18:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+20 = 2013-12-31T03:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-20 = 2014-01-01T19:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+21 = 2013-12-31T02:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-21 = 2014-01-01T20:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+22 = 2013-12-31T01:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-22 = 2014-01-01T21:59:59.000Z
20131231235959+23 = 2013-12-31T00:59:59.000Z  20131231235959-23 = 2014-01-01T22:59:59.000Z
```

Thanks,

Anand

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to a "just because this is the current range, it might not always be" mindset.  Given that an absolute offset greater than 12 is already present, anything less than a full day is therefore valid.  An absolute offset 24 or greater would be extremely bizarre, however (especially because that wouldn't _necessarily_ be 'one full day'....)

Answer (score 0):

From ISO 8601 :

> When it is required to indicate the difference between local time and UTC of day, the representation of the 
>   difference can be expressed in hours and minutes, or hours only. It shall be expressed as positive (i.e. with 
>   the leading plus sign [+]) if the local time is ahead of or equal to UTC of day and as negative (i.e. with the 
>   leading minus sign [-]) if it is behind UTC of day. The minutes time element of the difference may only be 
>   omitted if the difference between the time scales is exactly an integral number of hours. 
>   Basic format: ±hhmm Example: +0100 
>   ±hh +01 
>   Extended format: ±hh:mm Example: +01:00

It does not explicitly mention a range, but they do use the same letters as for hours. Given that [joda time uses ISO 8601 by default](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html) it seems implied that the range for the offset is the same as the range for the hours value of a time representation.